# Using the commands "heading", "random" and "random-float" in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

I have a question about some NetLogo commands.

I have a world in NetLogo that is closed (box). A part of the code has two types of walks.

walk 1:

```
right random 360
let x 2
forward x
```

walk 2:

```
set heading random-float 360
set real-x real-x + dx
set real-y real-y + dy      
let x 2
forward x
```

1. on the walk 1: the problem is that when an agent arrives at the edge of the world (closed world), the agent keeps turning around, little by little, until he turns into the world and starts walking again. But if I change the line of code right random 360 to right random-float 360. It doesn't happen that the bee turns around little by little until it finds the inner part of the world and starts moving again. Could anyone explain why this happens?
2. On walk 2: the problem is that some agents arrive at the edge of the world and don't die and don't do anything else. If I change the set heading random-float 360 line of code from walk 2 to right random-float 360. It doesn't happen that the agent doesn't die. Can anyone explain to me why this happens?

I already read in the NetLogo dictionary about the commands: "random" "random-float" and "heading" and I couldn't understand why this happens in my code. If anyone can help me understand these commands, I would be very grateful.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I am having trouble reproducing the behaviour you describe. Consider the below toy model:

```
to setup
  ca
  reset-ticks
  crt 2 [ pd ]
end

to go-1
  ask turtles [
    right random 360
    fd 2
  ]
  tick
end

to go-2
  ask turtles [
    set heading random-float 360
    forward 2
  ]
  tick
end
```

I can run either `go-1` or `go-2` 'forever' and the turtles do not seem to get stuck. Can you provide more detail (including the code that has your `turtles` `die`)?

Comment: Yes I will try to shorten the code to post. But, what I've noticed so far: In the walk 1 problem, that the agent turns around little by little when on the edge, I think this is related to the use of the "face" command together with the right random 360 But, that doesn't happen when I use "face" in conjunction with the right random-float 360 command. As for food service 2, I still don't know what can happen to the agent not dying. I will try to simplify the code to post here

Comment: Since “face” also sets the heading, it would be useful to see where and when “face” occurs.